# SoapClient with large data

Tags: php

I use SoapClient wsdl to retrive some data. It works fine if response is not too large, but if the response is too large, in my case 25 mb, it returns null.
Can anyone help me please?
Here's my code:

```
$opt = array('http' => array(
    'header' => "MyIdClient:" . $idclient . "\r\nMySecret:" . $mysecret . 
    "\r\nContent-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8"
));

$ctx = stream_context_create($opt);

$options  = array(
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => $ctx,
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
    'keep_alive' => 1,
    "features" => SOAP_WAIT_ONE_WAY_CALLS
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$search_result = $client->__doRequest($request, $endpoint, $action, 1, 0);
```